# jQuery AJAX POST always ends in a blank page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to submit a form on my page without refreshing it, using jQuery and ajax, I am also using Laravel.

The URL redirects to a route that updates the data from the form.

e.preventDefault() is not working, saw many posts and solutions to this which didn't work for me, I hope its not something obvious that I'm not seeing it.

I tried multiple things and still couldn't figure out where is the problem.

**FORM**

```
{{ Form::open(array('method'=>'post','class'=> 'profile_form ajaxpasswordreset','url'=>'/resetpassword')) }}
                <label for="old_password"> Current Password </label>    
                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::password('old_password', ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
                    @if ($errors->has('old_password'))
                        <span class="help-block">
                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('old_password') }}</strong>
                        </span>
                    @endif
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="old_password"> New Password </label>    
                    {!! Form::password('password', ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
                    @if ($errors->has('password'))
                        <span class="help-block">
                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                        </span>
                    @endif
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="old_password"> Password confirmation </label>    
                    {!! Form::password('password_confirmation', ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
                    @if ($errors->has('password_confirmation'))
                        <span class="help-block">
                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('password_confirmation') }}</strong>
                        </span>
                    @endif
                </div>
                    <button type="submit" id=""> Alterar Password </button>
                {{Form::close()}}
```

**JS**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('ajaxpasswordreset').on('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
            
            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                data: $('ajaxpasswordreset').serialize(),
                url: '/resetpassword', // This is the url we gave in the route
                success: function(response){
                    var stack_bar_bottom = {"dir1": "up", "dir2": "right", "spacing1": 0, "spacing2": 0};
                    new PNotify ({
                        title: "Sucesso",
                        text: "Password alterada com sucesso! ",
                        styling: "bootstrap3",
                        addclass: "stack-bottomright custom",
                        nonblock: {
                            nonblock: true
                        },
                        stack: stack_bar_bottom
                    });                  
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    var stack_bar_bottom = {"dir1": "up", "dir2": "right", "spacing1": 0, "spacing2": 0};
                    new PNotify ({
                        title: "Erro",
                        text: "Algo correu mal, tenta novamente.",
                        styling: "bootstrap3",
                        addclass: "stack-bottomright custom",
                        nonblock: {
                            nonblock: true
                        },
                        stack: stack_bar_bottom
                    });                     
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You check console?

Comment: yes, no errors related to this.

Comment: Did you try to use e.preventDefault() right before calling the ajax post?

Comment: Did you ensure the event handler is actually emmited? I assume you've got a typo here `$('ajaxpasswordreset')`. For classes you would need to define it like this `$('.ajaxpasswordreset')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your `head`

```
<meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

Modify your Form:

```
{!! Form::open(array('method'=>'post', 'id'=>'ajaxpasswordreset', 'class'=> 'profile_form','url'=>'/resetpassword')) !!}

    <label for="old_password"> Current Password </label>    
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::password('old_password', ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
        @if ($errors->has('old_password'))
            <span class="help-block">
            <strong>{{ $errors->first('old_password') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="old_password"> New Password </label>    
        {!! Form::password('password', ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
        @if ($errors->has('password'))
            <span class="help-block">
            <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="old_password"> Password confirmation </label>    
        {!! Form::password('password_confirmation', ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
        @if ($errors->has('password_confirmation'))
            <span class="help-block">
            <strong>{{ $errors->first('password_confirmation') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
    </div>

    //** modify submit button
    {!! Form::submit('Alterar Password',['id'='submitBtn, 'class'=>'btn btn-success btn-sm form-control'])!!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Modify your AJAX:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#ajaxpasswordreset').on('submit',function(e){
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                data: $('#ajaxpasswordreset').serialize(),
                url: '/resetpassword', // This is the url we gave in the route
                success: function(response){
                    var stack_bar_bottom = {"dir1": "up", "dir2": "right", "spacing1": 0, "spacing2": 0};
                    new PNotify ({
                        title: "Sucesso",
                        text: "Password alterada com sucesso! ",
                        styling: "bootstrap3",
                        addclass: "stack-bottomright custom",
                        nonblock: {
                            nonblock: true
                        },
                        stack: stack_bar_bottom
                    });                  
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    var stack_bar_bottom = {"dir1": "up", "dir2": "right", "spacing1": 0, "spacing2": 0};
                    new PNotify ({
                        title: "Erro",
                        text: "Algo correu mal, tenta novamente.",
                        styling: "bootstrap3",
                        addclass: "stack-bottomright custom",
                        nonblock: {
                            nonblock: true
                        },
                        stack: stack_bar_bottom
                    });                     
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your only problem is that your jQuery selector is broken, so it is not targeting the form.  So when you click submit, the normal form submission is happening, your Javascript is not firing, and your browser ends up on the form's `target` page.  Here's your selector:

```
$('ajaxpasswordreset').on('submit', function(e) {
```

You're missing a '.' to identify the class name.  It should be:

```
$('.ajaxpasswordreset').on('submit', function(e) {
```

I also notice you've got the same problem later on, serializing the form data:

```
data: $('ajaxpasswordreset').serialize(),
```

should be:

```
data: $('.ajaxpasswordreset').serialize(),
```

Comment: My bad, it was correct before, i just was trying to fix it and ended up that way.